# Change title of toolbar doesn't update when pressing standby and opening screen

Tags: android, android-toolbar

My title should update when going to standby and back.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun setContentViewBinding(): ActivityMainBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = setContentViewBinding()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val newRandomNr = Random().nextInt(50) + 1
        title = "new title " + newRandomNr
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/top_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

1. Open App, title shows correct random number
2. Press standby, open screen again.
3. Method onResume gets triggered, new random value but title does not update.

Comment: Can you post the code block where you are setting `title` in the toolbar? That code has to be in `onResume`.

Comment: @adnanyousafch added the code and the relevant build.gradle lines.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, title simply does not update when pressing standby. Using a reference to supportActionBar instead solves the problem.

```
    act.supportActionBar?.title = act.getString(R.string.title_messages)
```